# Is Geometry a prerequisite for Trigonometry?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I'm hoping to find out if you need a deep knowledge of Geometry (Say, all of Khan Academys Geometry topics) to work on Trigonometry.

I'm asking this because I need to take Calculus and people say the only Prerequisite for Calculus is Algebra 1, 2 and Trig. Geometry isn't.

Comment: Not really, but it helps a bit.

Comment: No. You literally just need to know what a right triangle is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to know geometry good enough.

For example if you know that if $CD$ is an altitude of $\Delta ABC$ and $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}$ then $CD^2=AD\cdot BD$, so you can prove the following inequality immediately.

For all $x>0$ prove that:
$$(e^x-1)\ln(1+x)\geq x^2,$$
otherwise it's much harder.

But to know trigonometry you need very good.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the answer. If you would take a look at the KhanAcademy website under Geometry, would you say I need to cover most of it? as I've explained I really need to prepare to take Calc (Knowing Algebra) and I'm trying to cut on things I don't necessarily require.

Comment: Btw, I think you didn't complete your sentence "But to know trigonometry you need very good."

Comment: It never hurts to learn more IMO. Also, some basics of proof and the relationships of certain parts of shapes may be needed for tackling some problems in ordinary calculus texts for first courses.

Comment: Yeah I know Sean, Its just that I'm trying to prepare to take Calc and I have 7 months to cover Algebra 2 and Trig, adding Geometry would get me on the edge there as I need enough time to prepare calc (gotta get a B+ or 85%)

Comment: @Eli S I think you need to use most of your time  for practicing  algebraic technique and trigonometry, but I recommend also repeat geometry a little bit.